# On a notion of "period" of Dirichlet character, modulo $k$, restricted to integers co-prime to $k$

Tags: number-theory, characters, arithmetic-functions

Let $\chi : \mathbb Z \to \mathbb C$ be a Dirichlet character mod $k$ ; i.e. $\chi (m+k)=\chi (m) , \forall m \in \mathbb Z$ ; $\chi (mn)=\chi(m)\chi (n),\forall m,n \in \mathbb Z$ and $\chi (n)=0$ iff gcd $(m,k)\ne 1$ .

Let us call $r\in \mathbb Z$ a "period" of $\chi$ if $\chi(m+r)=\chi (m) , \forall m\in \mathbb Z$ such that gcd $(m,k)=1$ .

Then does the set of all periods of $\chi$ form a subgroup of $\mathbb Z$  ?

I can show $0$ is a period but I can't show the sum of periods is period or even the negative of a period a period , mainly due to the restriction that the equality is satisfied for gcd $(m,k)=1$.

Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Write $\chi(n) = \tilde{\chi}(n) 1_{\gcd(n,k)=1}$ where $\tilde{\chi}$ is a primitive character $\bmod q | k$.  Then your periods are $q \mathbb{Z}$. (there is a subtlety here : if $\psi$ is a primitive character $\bmod p^e$ then we don't say it is a primitive character $\bmod p^{e+e'}$).

Comment: @reuns : how can you write that ?

Comment: More generally, use the Chinese remainder theorem to show any Dirichlet character $\chi \bmod k$ decomposes uniquely as $\prod_{p^e \| k} \chi_{p^e}$ where each $\chi_{p^e}$ is a Dirichlet character $\bmod p^e$ (defined by $\chi_{p^e}(n) = \chi(m)$ where $m \equiv 1 \bmod \frac{k}{p^e}, m \equiv n \bmod p^e$)

Comment: @reuns : okay, you can write every character $\chi$ mod $k$ as a product of the principal character mod $k$ and a primitive character mod the conductor (the smallest induced modulus) of $\chi$ . But from that how does the result about period follow ?

Comment: Assume $\tilde{\chi}(n) 1_{\gcd(n,d)=1}$ is $d$-periodic, and see what you get depending on $\gcd(d,q)$